# Вычисление из общего числа диапазоном числа

Tags: java

не знаю, как сформулировать свой вопрос:
У меня есть число, например: 500
Так же есть максимальное и минимальное число, допустим: min: 23, max: 26
Так же есть количество операций, за которое это нужно сделать.

Примерно так:
500
23
26
20

Мне нужно, чтобы он вычислял 20 раз и получилось ровно 500 после всех вычислений. То есть 500 - 23,5, потом 476,5 - 25,3. Только чтобы через 20 операций получилось 0.

```
 for(double amount = 0; days > 0; --days, ++amount)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        amount = rnd.nextDouble();
        if(test2)
        {
            amount = amount + test;
            kubov -= amount;
            String str;
            str = String.format("%.2f\n", amount);
            System.out.printf("Кубов: " + str + ", День: %d \n", days);
            System.out.println(kubov);
            test2 = false;
        } else {
            amount = test - amount;
            kubov -= amount;
            String str;
            str = String.format("%.2f\n", amount);
            System.out.printf("Кубов: " + str + ", День: %d \n", days);
            System.out.println(kubov);
            test2 = true;
        }
    }
```

Вот мой код, но он оставляет остаток + там не от максимума и минимума работает. Прошу не обращать внимания на переменные, ибо код я пишу для своих целей.

Comment: Это вам надо делать в цикле for. Предоставьте ваш код или его попытки и мы попробуем помочь с исправлением ошибок, а не решением задачи.

Comment: Отредактировал запись, посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

Как можно не обращать внимание на переменные? У вас в вопросе много не понятного.

То, что вы хотите, в кратце можно сделать так

```
      int min = 23;
    int max = 27;
    int score = 500;
    int count = 20;

    int dividerMin = score / min;
    int dividerMax = score / max;

    if (dividerMin < count) {
        while (count > 0 && score > 0) {
            score = score - min;
            System.out.println(score);
            count--;
        }
    } else if (dividerMax < count) {
        while (count > 0 && score > 0) {
            score = score - max;
            if (score < 0) {
                System.out.println(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println(score);
            }
            count--;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Увы и ах, делители очень маленькие чтобы уменьшить число за столько раз");
    }
```

Обработать вам это нужно так как вы хотите. Так же, здесь нет проверки на то, что будут делить на ноль или минимальное и максимальное значение будут нулями.

**UPD**

поправил код, немного.